# MYSQL - Multiple Concantenates in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that includes names and an Id:

```
Id  surname given
1   John    Doe
2   Fred    Smith
3   James   White
4   Dick    Jones
```

I have another table that groups these together
as Teams:

```
Team   Mem1  Mem2
A       1     2
B       3     4
C       1     4
```

Is there a way to Concatenate the names in a single query
to get a list of Teams and names?

Result would be:

```
A   John Doe    Fred Smith
B   James White Dick Jones
C   John Doe    Dick Jones
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice:

```
select 
    t.id,
    concat(n1.surname, ' ', n1.given) name1,
    concat(n2.surname, ' ', n2.given) name2
from teams t
inner join names n1 on n1.id = t.mem1
inner join names n2 on n2.id = t.mem2
```

If there are missing names, you can use `left join`s instead of `inner join`s.